# How can I change the location of folders that Eclipse creates in the Users\(user)\ directory?

Tags: eclipse, ide, usb-flash-drive

I am trying to make Eclipse run entirely on my flash drive so I could program anywhere on any computer, if it is Windows, really.

To accomplish this, I need some way to make the ".eclipse", ".p2", ".gitignore", and ".tooling" be *on the flash drive* and **not** *in the C:\Users(user)\ directory*.

Any solutions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use portable eclipse.. download from: https://sourceforge.net/projects/eclipseportable/

**Remember** you have to have JDK installed on the computers that you want to work on.